# Status of aggregate root dependent on the status of children

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, domain-driven-design

I am new to using DDD and need some advice. I have an aggregate root that contains a collection of children. The status of the root (IsFinished) depends on the children. Let's say I absolutely need the aggregate root to have a field '_someField', while there can be an unlimited number of aggregate roots with the same field value '_someField' and at the same time this field must be a string. According to this field, I need to find all aggregate roots that have some specific value (e.g. 'Test') and are in !IsFinished state. I am using EF6 and the search is quite slow. How would one generally go about solving something like this?

```
public class MyAggregateRoot: AggregateRoot
{
       private IList<Item> _items;
       private string _someField;
       public bool IsFinished => _items.All(i => i.Status == ItemStatus.Finished);
       
       public MyAggregateRoot()
       {
             _items = new List<Item>();
       }
       ...
}
```

For example, I was thinking of having a status variable inside the aggregate root that would be set to IsFinished the moment the last item is set to ItemStatus.Finished, but in that case it could happen for example that I have the status of the root set to Finished for some reason but some Item will not be in the finished state and therefore the data will be in an inconsistent state.

EDIT:

So let me ask it a little differently. What bothers me is whether it's good to always go through the collection to find some state, or for example some total - for example if I have a cart with some items, each item has a price and I want to calculate the total price.

One option would be to go through the collection of all items and add up their price. The other option would be to have a totalPrice variable in the Aggregare root (cart) and always recalculate that price appropriately when adding an item to the cart. I think the first solution is better from DDD point of view, but it will be worse from performance point of view.

Another example I can think of is some todo-list that contains individual tasks. Each task has a status not-completed or completed, and the todo-list has a status that is completed when all the todo-list's tasks are completed. If I had a really large number of todo-lists and I wanted to display all completed todo-lists, for example, I would also have to go through the tasks for all todo-lists and determine the todo-list status based on the status of all the tasks.

I'd like to get advice from an experienced developer who could, for example, explain to me when it's better to use the first solution and when to use the second (or a completely different one). Or tell me if, for example, the second solution somehow violates the DDD.

Comment: It's not clear where this `_someField` comes into play. "According to this field", what does that mean?

Comment: It is just a field that I use to retrieve from the repository all entities that have a specific value (e.g. "123456"). So it is not the id of the aggregate root, but just some variable by which I have to find all entities.

e.g. _repository.GetAllUnfinishedBySomeField(string id)

Comment: Since you mention slowness I think it's relevant to know what exactly happens. OTOH, which problem do you want to solve? Or, what is "something like this"? The status discrepancy or the slowness? Please focus on one problem per question.

Comment: First of all, I would like to know if it is good from DDD point of view to have such a structure also with respect to speed. Because if I want to get all the entities that are for example not finished yet, I have to load all the items and check their status, whereas if I have for example a new state variable, I would just look at the value of this state variable and I wouldn't have to go through all the items (which can be many).

Comment: On the other hand, I don't know if it's a good idea to have such a state variable, because then there might be a problem with inconsistency of states (the state variable will say that the aggregate root is in the finished state but all items won't be finished, for example).

Comment: That's two questions. And both questions are opinion-based. Also, nitpicking, speed is not a DDD concern. DDD is about business logic, while speed is a data access concern. You don't solve speed problems by DDD principles. If DDD prescribes that a set of objects is required ,this set  *must be delivered no matter what*. It's do the DAL to make it happen.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the use case.
If the use case states that there may be a large or unlimited number of children, it is technically not practical to put the children into the aggregate root.
On the other hand a small set of children in the parent may be handled by the ORM mapper (hint: I'm a Java developer, in my case it would be Hibernate) without performance problems.

Had a similar issue: My `Process` parent could have an unlimited number of `Activity` children. I decided to implement `Process` as an entity (being the aggregate root) and `Activity` as an value object with a reference to its `Process`. Changes to an `Activity` causing changes to its parent are propagated by events and handled asynchronously (so eventual consistency comes into play).

Vaughn Vernon discusses such design decisions in its "red book", that helped me a lot to come to a decision for implementation.

Comment: Thank you for the information. My Aggregate Root has only a limited amount of Items. However, I need to get all Aggregate Roots that are in some state (represented by the _someField field) - e.g. all that have a value in _someField equal to "SomeValue" and also only those that are unfinished (i.e. IsFinished must return false). The ORM (in this case EF 6) generates very slow queries, probably because all Items must always be loaded to determine the completion status. For this reason, I have asked here whether it is good to make the state of Aggregate Root depend on the states of its children.

Comment: One solution (so that I don't have to go through all Items to find out the state) is, in my opinion, just to make the IsFinished property independent of the children's states, but to change the Aggregate Root's state when the last Item (child) is completed. But in that case, it's basically extra information, since you can find out the state just from the state of your children, which is why I was interested in the opinion of other, more experienced developers.